# Wrong point position on map D3.JS

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm facing an issue with D3.JS, I got some coordinate (corresponding to the map in pixel unit), but when I draw them with D3, it seem's like it's reverting it to the original coordinate (not in pixel unit).[image: First Map with D3]

[image: Second is done manually]

So the first one is what I got with D3, the second is what I done manually, here is the code :

```
var width = 2154;
var height = 1024;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var valueline = d3.line()
    /*
    .defined(function(d) {
       return false;
    })
    */
    
    .defined(function(d) {
        return d.yVal != -1;
    })
    
    .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.xVal);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return y(d.yVal);
    })
   .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g");

// Get the data
var data = [{
    "xVal": 1285,
    "yVal": 424
}, {
    "xVal": 1285,
    "yVal": 424
}, {
    "xVal": 1285,
    "yVal": 424
}, {
    "xVal": 1285,
    "yVal": 424
}, {
    "xVal": 1285,
    "yVal": 424
}, {
    "xVal": 1285,
    "yVal": 424
}, {
    "xVal": 1283,
    "yVal": 459
}, {
    "xVal": 1283,
    "yVal": 459
}, {
    "xVal": 1283,
    "yVal": 459
}, {
    "xVal": 1272,
    "yVal": 493
}, {
    "xVal": 1258,
    "yVal": 525
}, {
    "xVal": 1258,
    "yVal": 525
}, {
    "xVal": 1258,
    "yVal": 525
}, {
    "xVal": 1258,
    "yVal": 525
}, {
    "xVal": 1258,
    "yVal": 525
}, {
    "xVal": 1258,
    "yVal": 525
}, {
    "xVal": 1258,
    "yVal": 525
}, {
    "xVal": 1223,
    "yVal": 529
}, {
    "xVal": 1188,
    "yVal": 533
}, {
    "xVal": 1153,
    "yVal": 537
}, {
    "xVal": 1118,
    "yVal": 541
}, {
    "xVal": 1083,
    "yVal": 545
}, {
    "xVal": 1048,
    "yVal": 549
}, {
    "xVal": 1013,
    "yVal": 553
}, {
    "xVal": 978,
    "yVal": 557
}, {
    "xVal": 943,
    "yVal": 561
}, {
    "xVal": 907,
    "yVal": 565
}, {
    "xVal": 872,
    "yVal": 568
}, {
    "xVal": 837,
    "yVal": 572
}, {
    "xVal": 802,
    "yVal": 576
}, {
    "xVal": 767,
    "yVal": 580
}, {
    "xVal": 732,
    "yVal": 584
}, {
    "xVal": 697,
    "yVal": 588
}, {
    "xVal": 662,
    "yVal": 592
}, {
    "xVal": 627,
    "yVal": 596
}, {
    "xVal": 627,
    "yVal": 596
}, {
    "xVal": 592,
    "yVal": 593
}, {
    "xVal": 592,
    "yVal": 593
}, {
    "xVal": 557,
    "yVal": 597
}, {
    "xVal": 557,
    "yVal": 597
}, {
    "xVal": 557,
    "yVal": 597
}, {
    "xVal": 557,
    "yVal": 597
}, {
    "xVal": 557,
    "yVal": 597
}, {
    "xVal": 557,
    "yVal": 597
}, {
    "xVal": 531,
    "yVal": 573
}, {
    "xVal": 531,
    "yVal": 573
}, {
    "xVal": 511,
    "yVal": 545
}, {
    "xVal": 490,
    "yVal": 516
}, {
    "xVal": 469,
    "yVal": 488
}, {
    "xVal": 469,
    "yVal": 488
}, {
    "xVal": 453,
    "yVal": 456
}, {
    "xVal": 438,
    "yVal": 425
}, {
    "xVal": 438,
    "yVal": 425
}, {
    "xVal": 421,
    "yVal": 392
}, {
    "xVal": 411,
    "yVal": 358
}, {
    "xVal": 411,
    "yVal": 358
}, {
    "xVal": 395,
    "yVal": 327
}, {
    "xVal": 379,
    "yVal": 295
}, {
    "xVal": 364,
    "yVal": 264
}, {
    "xVal": 348,
    "yVal": 232
}, {
    "xVal": 348,
    "yVal": 232
}, {
    "xVal": 338,
    "yVal": 198
}, {
    "xVal": 338,
    "yVal": 198
}, {
    "xVal": 338,
    "yVal": 198
}, {
    "xVal": 338,
    "yVal": 198
}, {
    "xVal": 313,
    "yVal": 174
}, {
    "xVal": 313,
    "yVal": 174
}, {
    "xVal": 313,
    "yVal": 174
}, {
    "xVal": 313,
    "yVal": 174
}, {
    "xVal": 278,
    "yVal": 162
}, {
    "xVal": 244,
    "yVal": 154
}, {
    "xVal": 210,
    "yVal": 145
}, {
    "xVal": 175,
    "yVal": 137
}, {
    "xVal": 141,
    "yVal": 129
}, {
    "xVal": 107,
    "yVal": 120
}]

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data,
    function (d) {
        return d.xVal;
    }));
y.domain([
    0, d3.max(data,
        function (d) {
            return d.yVal;
        })
]);

svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

// add "dots" (circles) for each "valid" data point
// using same validity function as used above for line
svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data.filter(function(d) {
        return d.yVal != -1;
    }))
    .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('r', 5)
      .attr('cx', function (d) {
        return x(d.xVal);
      })
      .attr('cy', function (d) {
        return y(d.yVal);
      })
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="map.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
body {
    font: 12px Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

svg {
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/augustin-laurent/Visualization_Tool/master/map/top_down_map0.png");
    padding: 30px;
}

path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 2;
}

circle {
   fill: red;
   stroke: turquoise;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    stroke: #BBB;
    stroke-width: 1;
}

.axis text {
    fill: #766;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

The data used are in the var data, as I said upper, the point are not well positioned, I don't know the issue but there is something interesting before I was using data in an another unit and the plot look like this with Spyder :
[image: Plot Spyder]

So if someone know why D3 is acting like that It could really help me, thanks for the help, I don't know if I'm clear on explanation, but thanks in advance for any help !